# how to use $request->all() on controller and blade view in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, request

in Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search_cons = $request->all();
        $search_con = $search_cons->name;  //error place
        return $search_cons.$search_con;
    }
```

`->name` this place has the error

Trying to get property of non-object

Or in blade.view

```
<p>{{$search_cons->name}}</p>   has the error
```

Trying to get property of non-object

But if I use

```
$search_cons=$request->input('name');
```

on controller

the blade view
`<p>{{$search_cons}}</p>`  will work ok!

I want the `$search=request->all()` so I can freely use `$search->name` on my blade view
How can I fix the question?
PS: I tried  `$resquest('name')` still not to work
`Request::all()` ->tell me the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$request->all()` it returns all the inputs submitted in `array` format. So in your case, you can do

```
$search_cons = $request->all(); // dd($search_cons) so you can see its structure
$search_con = $search_cons['name']; // instead of ->name since it's not an object anymore
```

And anyway, you can skip the `$request->all()` thing - you can actually just do this directly:
`$request->name`.

EDIT:
You can cast the array as an object using `(object)`

```
$search_cons = (object) $request->all();
```

this will still let you use `$search_cons->name`

Comment: Thanks~
but I use fond the question
Undefined index: name
Because index is my web home 
so first time I go the the website I don't have the name data
When I post the data from the website again then I have the name data

So how can I escape the error message from the first time

Comment: I updated my answer to give you more choices, depending of which you prefer. You can do `$search_con = isset( $search_cons->name) ?  $search_cons->name : ''`; to prevent the error for that

Answer (score 1):

`$search_cons` is an array, not an object:

```
$search_con = $search_cons['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search_cons = $request->all(); //returns array
        $search_con = $search_cons['name'];  //error place
        return $search_cons.$search_con;
    }
```

Or you can do like this

```
request()->name //request() isa global helper function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

In Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {
     $search = $request->all();     
     return ['search' => $search];
  }
```

In Blade

> <p>Name : {{$search['name'] ? $search['name'] : ''}} </p>